# Bind instances dynamically in Guice

Tags: java, guice

<sub>Note: despite the similar name, the answer of [Dynamically bind instances using guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225234/dynamically-bind-instances-using-guice) can't solve my problem since I need all the injections directly injected and not in a map.</sub>

I have a set of pairs of `Class` -> instances. They are stored in a Guava's `ClassToInstanceMap`. I want to pass that `ClassToInstanceMap` to my custom `Module` and go through each entry to perform the actual binding. How do I do that?

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableClassToInstanceMap;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Module;

public class InstanceModuleBuilder {
  private final ImmutableClassToInstanceMap.Builder<Object> instancesBuilder = ImmutableClassToInstanceMap.builder();
  public <T> InstanceModuleBuilder bind(Class<T> type, T instance) {
    instancesBuilder.put(type, instance);
    return this;
  }
  public Module build() {
    return new InstanceModule(instancesBuilder.build());
  }
  static class InstanceModule extends AbstractModule {
    private final ImmutableClassToInstanceMap<Object> instances;
    InstanceModule(ImmutableClassToInstanceMap<Object> instances) {
      this.instances = instances;
    }
    @Override protected void configure() {
      for (Class<?> type : instances.keySet()) {
        bind(type).toInstance(instances.getInstance(type)); // Line with error
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile the above code, I get the following error:

```
InstanceModuleBuilder.java:[38,52] incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: capture#1 of ?
    upper bounds: capture#2 of ?,java.lang.Object
```

I also tried the following bindings:

```
for (Map.Entry<? extends Object,Object> e: instances.entrySet()) {
  bind(e.getKey()).toInstance(e.getValue());
}
```

Or

```
for (Map.Entry<? extends Object,Object> e: instances.entrySet()) {
  bind(e.getKey()).toInstance(e.getKey().cast(e.getValue()));
}
```

But none compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got rid of the generics and it worked:

```
    @Override protected void configure() {
      for (Class type : instances.keySet()) {
        bind(type).toInstance(instances.getInstance(type));
      }
    }
```